# Symfony Validator Array for a Group

Tags: symfony, validation, silex

i am using Validator Component for validate an array.

My validations are conditionals, so i create groups.

But i can not get it work correctly. The validator ignores the groups when checks contraints.

This is my (unit)test:

```php
public function testValidator()
{
   $book = array(
        'title' => 'My Book',
        'author' => array(
            'first_name' => 'Fabien',
            'last_name'  => 'Potencier',
        ),
    );

    $constraint = new Assert\Collection(array(
        'groups' => array('MyGroup'),
        'fields' => array(
            'title' => new Assert\Length(array('min' => 10, 'groups' => 'MyGroup')),
            'author' => new Assert\Collection(array(
                'groups' => array('MyGroup'),
                'fields' => array(
                    'first_name' => array(new Assert\NotBlank(), new Assert\Length(array('min' => 10))),
                    'last_name'  => new Assert\Length(array('min' => 10, 'groups' => 'MyGroup')),
                )
            )),
        )
    ));
    // $this->v is the validator service
    $errors = $this->v->validateValue($book, $constraint, null, array('MyGroup'));

    $this->assertEquals(1, $errors->count(), $errors);
}
```

And the results are:

```
PHPUnit 3.7.14 by Sebastian Bergmann.

Configuration read from phpunit.xml

.F

Time: 0 seconds, Memory: 3.00Mb

There was 1 failure:


1) WebFactory\ValidationNormalizer\Tests\ValidationNormalizerTest::testValidator
[title]:
    This value is too short. It should have 10 characters or more.
[author][first_name]:
    This value is too short. It should have 10 characters or more.
[author][last_name]:
    This value is too short. It should have 10 characters or more.

Failed asserting that 3 matches expected 1.

src/WebFactory/ValidationNormalizer/Tests/ValidationNormalizerTest.php:64

FAILURES!
Tests: 2, Assertions: 2, Failures: 1.
```

I want only validate MyGroup constraints.

Where is the error?

Answer (score 0):

You have added the whole collection to your group 'MyGroup'.

```
  'author' => new Assert\Collection(array(
      'groups' => array('MyGroup'),
```

Therefore it validates the whole array

```
'author' => array(
     'first_name' => 'Fabien',
      'last_name'  => 'Potencier',
),
```

... if you specify validation group as 'MyGroup'. This behavior is correct.

If you only want to validate 'title' and 'lastname' when using validation group 'MyGroup' use:

```
$constraint = new Assert\Collection(array(
    'fields' => array(
        'title' => new Assert\Length(array('min' => 10, 'groups' => 'MyGroup')),
        'author' => new Assert\Collection(array(
            'fields' => array(
                'first_name' => array(new Assert\NotBlank(), new Assert\Length(array('min' => 10))),
                'last_name'  => new Assert\Length(array('min' => 10, 'groups' => 'MyGroup')),
            )
        )),
    )
));
```

Comment: No differences. Removing 'groups' => array('MyGroup'), for Assert\Collection do not validate title or author.last_name for MyGroup.

This call is correctly?

`$this->v->validateValue($book, $constraint, null, array('MyGroup'));`